# spring inject attributes on mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, spring.net

I am working with and mvc4 web application and using spring.net v2 M2 for the dependency injection.

I am wondering is possible to inject in to my controllers, filters/attributes on to the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Same as in **Asp.Net MVC3**: Register a custom spring aware `FilterAttributeFilterProvider` derive your application from `SpringMvcApplication` instead of `HttpApplication` and see the magic work. Sample impl. not production ready:

```
public class FilterProvider : FilterAttributeFilterProvider, IApplicationContextAware
{
    public IApplicationContext ApplicationContext
    {
        set;
        get;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        var filters = base.GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);
        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            ApplicationContext.ConfigureObject(filter.Instance, filter.Instance.GetType().Name);
            yield return filter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this information - is it possible to use this to only inject in to specific controllers and not all?

Comment: The code does property injection into ActionFilter objects. Instantiation and resolving mvc controller is supported out of the spring.net box, imho spring raises an exception when the controller is not found in the config; however you could fallback to the default MVC behavior (Activator.CreateInstance).